# How to define path to manifest file for crashlytics

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I use custom build directory for gradle.
It is set in the following way:

```
gradlew_runner.bat --gradle-user-home="$(GradleUserHome)" -PbuildDir="$(BuildDir)"
```

(these parameters are passed to `gradlew.bat`)

Crashlytics plugin throws an `com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.ManifestData$ManifestIOException` exception,

because it is trying to find manifest in my source directory `myproject\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`

but my manifest is located in `$(BuildDir)\myproject\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`.

Crashlytics shows following message:

> usage: com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools
>
> -androidManifest    Path to AndroidManifest.xml)

But these parameters can't be passed directly to `gradlew.bat`.

Is there any way to set path to manifest in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting Michael Bonnel of Crashlytics:

> Just add this in your build.gradle flavor:

```
crashlytics { 
  manifestPath = 'path/to/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

> This will override where we are looking!

And in my case, I'm passing build directory as command line argument `-PbuildDir="somepath"`,
so final solution is:

```
if (buildDir) {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            crashlytics {
                manifestPath = "$buildDir/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update 20.08.2014: I tried crashlytics with new project and same mechanism of passing `buildDir` from command line, `manifestPath` is no longer needed, because crashlytics finds it correctly.